# Proof using epsilon criterion for supremum

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E = \{a+b \mid a \in (-2,-1], b \in [1,2) \}$. Show using the epsilon criterion that $\sup E = 1$.

I was not very familiar with the epsilon criterion, but it seems that I need to show $1$ is an upper bound and then that $1-\varepsilon < a+b$ for all $\varepsilon$?

Since $a+b < -1 + 2 = 1$ it would be that $1$ is an upper bound for the set. Now if $\varepsilon >0$, then from $1- \varepsilon <a+b$ I feel like I should consider cases? If $a=-1$, then $1-\varepsilon <-1+b \implies 3-\varepsilon<b \iff \varepsilon > 3-b$?

Comment: The question is wrong. The supremum is $1$.

Comment: Sorry. Edited...

Comment: You only need to show that for each $\epsilon>0$,**there exists** such $a$ and $b$, i.e. pick $a$ and $b$ (necessarily dependent on $\epsilon$) which satisfy $a+b>1-\epsilon$. It is obviously not true for all pairs $(a,b)$, take $a=-1$ and $b=1$ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly $1$ is an upper bound. To show that the sup is $1$ we have to prove the following:

Given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $a \in (-2,-1]$ and $b \in [1,2)$ such that $1-\epsilon  <a+b$.
For this take $0<\delta <\min \{\epsilon /2,1 \} $ and take $a=-1-\delta, b=2-\delta$. I will let you verify that this works.

Comment: I meant to take $\delta <\epsilon /2$. Thanks for your comment. @trancelocation

Comment: Could you elaborate on how did you come up with $\delta < \min\{ \varepsilon/2, 1\}$? I see that we need both inequalities hold $a > -1 - \varepsilon$, $b > 2 - \varepsilon$, so $\varepsilon > -1-a$, and $\varepsilon > 2-b$?

Comment: $\delta <\epsilon /2$ is to make $a+b >1-\epsilon$ and $\delta <1$ is required to make sure that our choice of $a, b$ lie in the given intervals $(-2,-1]$ and $[1,2)$ respectively.  @Georgi